# Haskell: how do I write an instance for this Class

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, if I have an interface like

```
class Eq a => Lol l a b where
    ...
```

how should I declare simple instances?
If I try something like

```
class Lol1 a b
instance Lol Lol1 A B
```

it complains that the first argument of Lol should have kind * -> * -> * while Lol1 has kind

```
* -> * -> Constraint
```

Comment: Are you sure that you did not mean ``data Lol1 ...``? Otherwise it looks like you are trying to parametrize a class with another class.

Comment: I'm sure, I'm using MultiParamTypeClasses and trying to understand some code..

Comment: Could you then provide some self-contained code, something that you would expect to work if written correctly? I'm not quite sure what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Forget MPTC for now - you can not parameterize one class instance with another class in this manner.  Consider:  `instance Eq Ord`  - pretty meaningless, huh?

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is a kind mismatch. Kinds are the "types" of types. For example `Int` has the kind `*`. `*` is used to represent any haskell value type, `Int`s, `Bool`s, whatever.

So you're looking for something with the kind `* -> * -> *`. This takes in 2 things of kind `*` and returns a `*`. An example would be `Either`.

The problem is that your typeclass `Lol1` doesn't have the kind `* -> * -> *`, it's meant to be used on the left side of a `=>`, those things have the kind `Constraint`. Other things like this are equality constraints, `a ~ Int` or implicit parameters.

So this leads to the inevitable conclusion that you can't use classes as parameters of other classes like below. It's just not well kinded, ever. It's like saying `instance Foo (a ~ Int)`.

```
 class Foo k where
     foo :: ... => k a -> ...
 -- Or in general, On the right side of an =>
 foo' :: ... => Foo Foo -> ..
```

So instead you have to use datatypes,

```
 data Lol1 a b = ...
```

I can't provide any details about what `...` should be without more code for `Lol`.

Comment: "So this leads to the inevitable conclusion that you can't use classes as parameters of other classes" -- if I understand correctly, this claim is false. https://gist.github.com/luqui/6640808

Answer (score 1):

Did you read [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)?

Especially the part about [typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-102) and maybe the part about [kinds](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo) should be very helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the entire scope of your program, I can't say if this is the solution you want. But you can indeed use classes and treat them as types in the instance of a class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
 MultiParamTypeClasses,
 KindSignatures,
 ConstraintKinds,
 FlexibleInstances,
 UndecidableInstances
 #-}

import GHC.Prim (Constraint)

class Lol1 a b -- Lol1 has kind * -> * -> Constraint
class Lol2 a   -- Lol2 has kind * -> Constraint

-- Note the explicit 'kind' signature for type var 'l'. This is necessary
class Eq a => Lol (l :: * -> * -> Constraint) a b where

instance Eq b => Lol Lol1 b c
-- instance Eq b => Lol Lol2 b c -- won't work

data A; data B
```

The only thing you can do with the class 'type' variable is use it to constrain other type variables, or pass it to another class.

```
class (l a b) => Lol (l :: * -> * -> Constraint) a b where

instance Lol1 a b -- removing this breaks the line below
instance Lol Lol1 a b
```